# spring-data-rest and micro-services: Entity with @OneToOne relationship with Entity in another spring-data-rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-data-rest

In my spring-data-rest application I have the following entities

```
@Entity
public class com.foo.client.Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 48)
    public String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @OneToOne
    public Bar bar;        
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 48)
    public String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public String name;        
}
```

I have JpaRepository for each entity class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "foos", path = "foos")
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {
}


@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "bars", path = "bars")
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, String> {
}
```

I create an instance for both Foo and Bar using:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"id": "urn:foo:test:0"}' http://localhost:8000/foos


curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"id": "urn:bar:test:0", "name" : "0"}' http://localhost:8000/bars
```

I then associate the Bar instance to the Foo instance using:

```
curl -i -X PUT -d "http://localhost:8000/bars/urn:bar:test:0\n"
  -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" "http://localhost:8000/foos/urn:foo:test:0/bar"
```

When the two entities are defined in the same spring-data-rest service endpoint then all is well and I can get the bar instance associated with the foo instance using:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" "http://localhost:8000/foos/urn:foo:test:0/bar"
```

Question: Looking at the postgresdb where entities are stored I see an association table FOO_BAR where there are two columns holding the id of each entity. However, I do not see where the URL for bar is stored and would like to understand where it is stored.

Now if I split my app into two separate spring-data-rest services one foo-service for Foo and another bar-service for bar at separate ports, and also split the Repository classes between two project, then creating the association does not work and I get a 404. See modified code below:

I create an instance for both Foo and Bar using:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"id": "urn:foo:test:0"}' http://localhost:8000/foos


curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"id": "urn:bar:test:0", "name" : "0"}' http://localhost:8001/bars
```

I then associate the Bar instance to the Foo instance using:

```
curl -i -X PUT -d "http://localhost:8001/bars/urn:bar:test:0\n"
  -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" "http://localhost:8000/foos/urn:foo:test:0/bar"
```

This last request above gives me a 404 when Foo and Bar are managed by different spring-data-rest services.

How can I get the second case to work?

Note I used [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) excellent resource for my example.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when the code was split across two separate services (separate modules in same multi-project gradle) I also need the service with the owner entity (foo-service) to have a BarRepository for the owned Entity (Bar). When I copy the BarRepository from bar-service module to foo-service module then I no longer get a 404 and the relationship between Foo to Bar can be observed in the API. Of course this only works if foo-service and bar-service share the same database (which at present in my case they do).

I would be interested in an answer that describes how to solve this problem in a general case where the two services do not share a database.